# audit log for any persisted changes, without using database triggers, instead use spring/hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, logging, auditing

Everytime a user makes an alteration to a record and saves it. I want an audit log for that change.  Say for example we have a customer table and the gui shows customer info and sales, I also want to the gui to show an audit log for that customer. Who by and when every change was made to customer.

I could use database triggers and on every insert/update/delete create a new record in a log table (be it one log table for all tables, or one each e.g. customer_log).

However, I am using Spring 3.1 and hibernate 4 and was trying to keep everything (business logic) in Java and outside of the database and spocs/triggers.  I have the idea that spring aop might be appropriate ... ?

For every `session.save(myEntity)` that occurs on my system, I also want to do an `session.save(myEntityLog)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two choices for frameworks thad handle this in the application Lazyer

- [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers)
- [Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades) (has some support) and [Spring Data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) too.
- or you do it by hand, with help of `PostPersis`t and friends.